# Executing SQL query on multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I know my post has a very similar title to other ones in this forum, but I really couldn't find the answer I need.

Here is my problem, I have a SQL Server running on my Windows Server. Inside my SQL Server, I have around 30 databases. All of them have the same tables, and the same stored procedures.

Now, here is the problem, I have this huge script that I need to run in all of these databases. I wish I could do it just once against all my databases.

I tried a couple things like go to "view" >> registered servers >> local server groups >> new server registration. But this solution is for many servers, not many databases.

I know I could do it by typing the database name, but the query is really huge, so it would take too long to run in all databases.

Does anybody have any idea if that is possible?

Comment: You can't shorten the time needed to execute the query against different databases. This seems to be a [duplicate of question posted on DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/907/how-to-execute-sql-against-all-dbs-on-a-server) which should help you out :-)

Comment: why does typing the database name would take long to run in all databases ?

Comment: You can use EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @stored_procedure. ,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ApexSQL Propagate](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_propagate.aspx) is the tool which can help in this situation. It is used for executing single or multiple scripts on multiple databases, even multiple servers. What you should do is simply select that script, then select all databases against which you want to execute that script:

[image: select databases]

When you load scripts and databases you should just click the “Execute” button and wait for the results:

[image: click the execute button]

Comment: It has its quirks (encoding, having issues with my old SQL 2008 instances, overwriting the .sql source files on execution), but overall seems ok. Also, first setup is a little clunky. It even managed to empty one of the input .sql files when overwriting it. Again, seems ok though.

Comment: It doesn't work, I click on "Execute" and it seems to be running just fine until when it's finished then it says "Failed" for all databases.I tested my connections and they are good so I don't know why it won't run my scripts.

Answer (score 15):

Consider running the script in [SQLCMD Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) from SSMS (Query--SQLCMD Mode).  This way, you can save the script to a file and run it in the context of each of the desired databases easily:

```
USE DB1;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourLargeScript.sql
GO
USE DB2;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourLargeScript.sql
GO
USE DB3;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourLargeScript.sql
GO
```

This technique can also be used to run the script against databases on other servers with the addition of a `:CONNECT` command. The connection reverts back to initial server/database after execution of the entire script:

```
:CONNECT SomeServer
USE DB4;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourLargeScript.sql
GO
:CONNECT SomeOtherServer
USE DB5;
:r C:\SqlScript\YourLargeScript.sql
GO
```

**Important gotcha**: Note `GO` batch separators are needed for `:CONNECT` to work as expected. I recommend including `GO` in the the invoking script like the above example but `GO` as the last line in the `:r` script file will also provide the desired results. Without `GO` in this example (or at the end of the script file), the script would run twice on SomeServer and not run against SomeOtherServer at all.

Comment: Dan Guzman, I think your suggestion would be the best way to do it since my file has around 45000 lines of code. I am going to try it and I let everybody know! Thank you very much

Answer (score 15):

You can use [WHILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql) loop over all database names and inside loop execute query with [EXECUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql). I think that statement `SET @dbname = ...` could be better, but this works too.

```
DECLARE @rn INT = 1, @dbname varchar(MAX) = '';
WHILE @dbname IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @dbname = (SELECT name FROM (SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn 
        FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN('master','tempdb')) t WHERE rn = @rn);

    IF @dbname <> '' AND @dbname IS NOT NULL
        EXECUTE ('use '+QUOTENAME(@dbname)+';

            /* Your script code here */
            UPDATE some_table SET ... ;

        ');
    SET @rn = @rn + 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write script like this

```
DECLARE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM Sys.Databases
WHERE name NOT IN('master', 'tempdb') 

OPEN CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES

FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
  EXEC('UPDATE '+ @DB_NAME + '..SameTableNameAllDb SET Status=1')
  FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMESINTO INTO @DB_NAME
END

CLOSE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES
```

Comment: Doesn't work. One problem is the name of the cursor in the last FETCH statement, but even fixing that I get very strange behavior.

Comment: @OskarBerggren I figured it out.
After `FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMESINTO INTO @DB_NAME` you need the statement `FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME` otherwise you get an infinite loop on the first record

Answer (score 1):

**this is the normal way of doing this :**

suppose you want to do a select on database DBOther than it would be :

```
select * from DBOther..TableName
```

Also check if the table or view is on the dbo schema, if not you should add the schema also : Please notice I use only one dot now after the database name

```
select * from DBOther.dbo.ViewName
```

If any of the databases is on another server on another machine, than make sure the Database is in the Linked Server.
Then you can access the table or view on that database via:

```
SELECT * FROM [AnotherServerName].[DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

**Here is another way that does not requires typing the database name :**

```
use DB1
go

select * from table1
go

use DB2
go

select * from table1
go
```

Note that this will only work if the tables and fields are exact the same on each database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to run the same script on a set of databases. Just change the filter in the *insert* line.

```
declare @dbs table (
  dbName varchar(100),
  done bit default 0
)

insert @dbs select [name], 0 FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE [Name] like 'targets_%'

while (exists(select 1 from @dbs where done = 0))
begin
  declare @db varchar(100);
  select top 1 @db = dbName from @dbs where done = 0;
  exec ('
    use [' + @db + '];
    update table1 set
      col1 = '''',
      col2 = 1
    where id = ''45b6facb-510d-422f-a48c-687449f08821''
  ');
  print @db + ' updated!';
  update @dbs set done = 1 where dbName = @db;
end
```

If your SQL Server version does not support table variables, just use Temp Tables but don`t forget to drop them at the end of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirement, you can do this:

```sql
declare @dbName nvarchar(100)
declare @script nvarchar(max)
declare @dbIndex bigint = 0
declare @dbCount bigint = (
    select count(*) from
        sys.databases

    )
declare crs_databases cursor for
(
    select
        [name]
    from
        sys.databases   
)
open crs_databases
fetch next from crs_databases into @dbName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @dbIndex = @dbIndex+1
    set @script = concat(@script,
        ' select Id from ['+@dbName+']..YourTableName ',        
        case 
            when @dbIndex = @dbCount then ''
            else 'union'
        end)
    fetch next from crs_databases into @dbName
end

select @script
close crs_databases
deallocate crs_databases
```

Please note that the double dotted notation assumes that the schema is dbo. Otherwise, you need to explicitly write down the schema.

```
select Id from ['+@dbName+'].schema.YourTableName
```

When you need to execute stored procedures on each server, the `@script` variable will have another content.