# Using SQL Table Value for From Clause

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I'm trying to write a SQL script which pulls the value of a cell in a given table across multiple databases in a single server. The table has the same name and path across several databases.  I'd like to list the specific cell values in a new table.

My first step is to pull all of the database names into a temporary table and then concatenate the table path to it.  The code I use is

```
SELECT name
INTO #dbtablepaths
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name like 'FTR[0-9]%'

UPDATE #dbtablepaths 
SET name=CONCAT(name, '.ftrdbo.[File]')
```

This will create a table of dbo paths that when queried will return the following:

__|__name_____________

1 | FTR108547.ftrdbo.[File]

2 | FTR564187.ftrdbo.[File]

3 | FTR849721.ftrdbo.[File]

I can then pull one of these dbo paths using the following query

```
SELECT name FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) as rownumber,
    name
    FROM #dbtablepaths
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

This will return the first dbo path in the table which is FTR108547.ftrdbo.[File].

If I simply copy that path into a SELECT statement (see below) it will bring up the table as intended.

```
SELECT * FROM FTR108547.ftrdbo.[File]
```

However, if I try to use a subquery to enter that into the FROM clause of a SELECT statement then the query simply returns the dbo path again. E.G.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT name FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) as rownumber,
        name
        FROM #dbtablepaths
    ) AS foo
    WHERE rownumber = 1
)
```

I would expect this query to pull the File table but instead it just returns the dbo path again. I.E. FTR108547.ftrdbo.[File]

Is there a way to use table cell values to create queries like this? I know the SELECT statement is returning a table and not a string.  Is there a way to convert this table value to a string that can be used in a subsequent SELECT query?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to forgive me as i am unable to make comments yet  but you will probally want to take a look at the answers in this post

[Executing SQL query on multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336171/executing-sql-query-on-multiple-databases)

it has several examples that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

This will assign the result into a variable @tabname and use it in the SELECT

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tabname VARCHAR(100)

SELECT name
  INTO #dbtablepaths
  FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
 WHERE name like 'FTR[0-9]%'

UPDATE #dbtablepaths 
   SET name=CONCAT(name, '.ftrdbo.[File]')

SELECT @tabname = name
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) AS rownumber,
               name
          FROM #dbtablepaths
       ) AS foo
 WHERE rownumber = 1

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tabname

EXEC(@sql)
```