# ASP.NET MVC web system publish to multi domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have web system (ASP.NET MVC), each client has its own domain and DB.

Now, we are making development on some modules, and I need to upload updates to each domain and deploy databases changes on each database (So, if I have 10 clients I need to repeat this task 10 times)

I want to know how to deploy updates on all domains and databases at once.

Regards,

Comment: What is your current approach of deploying changes to one client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CI/CD (Continuous integration/ Continuous deployment) for this. Please look at the below link-

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3271126/ci-cd/what-is-cicd-continuous-integration-and-continuous-delivery-explained.html

Helpful applications are Teamcity, Octopus. Also, for deploying database changes, you can create a console application in which you can add sql files. Which when deployed will be added to the client Database. You can look at the below link-

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5164/basic-database-continuous-integration-and-delivery-cicd-using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tools as following :
to execute script on multiple db's you can use tool called "Apex Sql"
[Executing SQL query on multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336171/executing-sql-query-on-multiple-databases)

to publish on different folders you can use tool called "fling"
https://www.nchsoftware.com/fling/index.html