# Dynamically UPDATE strings to correct misspellings across all databases, if table and column names are known

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have several customer databases that contain tables and columns of the same name, and those tables contain misspellings in a few fields. The IDs are different in all tables, however. I want to easily update the string text for those columns across all database. I know the names of the main 5 databases, but there are more than 50. I accomplished this for one database, as that was what was originally requested, but I was told to do it dynamically.

Example of one fix that worked for ONE database:

```
 UPDATE dbo.QuestionnaireQuestionLookup
 SET QuestionText = 'Person with a serious mental illness'
 WHERE  QuestionnaireQuestionId = 18 AND QuestionnaireFormTypeId = 11;
```

The IDs vary. I am trying to get this to work within all databases, even if the name is not known. I know that the Column and Table names are always the same, but I need to update it across all DBs, regardless of the IDs in each table. I do not think omitting the IDs will solve this issue. Any tips would be much appreciated. I could not find any questions/answers here that applied to my exact scenario.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results to illustrate the problem.

Comment: There are plenty of questions out there on how to iterate through all your databases though, if thats of help.

Comment: @DaleK I am just trying to get the above query to work in every every database in my system. There are several tables with the name "QuestionnaireQuestionLookup" and the misspellings occur in "QuestionText" and other columns within my databases. I am working with at least 5 at a time, but I only know how to update one at a time using the query above: 
 "UPDATE dbo.QuestionnaireQuestionLookup
 SET QuestionText = 'Person with a serious mental illness'"


"Mental" is misspelled as "Metal". The one UPDATE query corrected that in one database only.

Comment: You can only update 1 table in 1 database at a time... but you can write a cursor to iterate over the databases using dynamic SQL. As I said there are loads of examples of doing this.

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for your comments. I am not sure how cursors work, but I will look more into them. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336171/executing-sql-query-on-multiple-databases

Comment: Since you mention that the IDs can vary between tables/databases I don't see how a cursor will help here. As this is a spelling correction task one assumes you have a file, spreadsheet, etc., somewhere that captures the incorrect spellings along with the corrections, so it seems that a String-based query on `QuestionText` rather than an ID-based one on `QuestionnaireQuestionId` would be more appropriate matching on the incorrect text and `SET`ing with the corrected.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for your response. This is what I thought of trying and what someone else gave me a clue on, but I am not sure how I can get it to work across all databases. I do not know the name of all DBs that have the same table and column names -- only about 5:

"UPDATE dbo.QuestionnaireQuestionLookup
 SET QuestionText = 'Person with a serious mental illness'"

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_msforeachdb to loop databases:

```sql
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'USE [?];

print ''Database: ?''
if object_id(''yourtableName'') is not null -- table must exists
BEGIN
   
   -- Do something clever here
   update sometable set somefield = ''somevalue'' where somethingorOther=1

END
'
```

The procedure runs the provided sql string in all your databases. The database being run is passed in the "?", so one can do things like USE [?] to change to that database.

Note that procedure has some quirks, but works mostly ok, you can search around for alternatives as well.

Inside the string, you check so your table actually exists by doing OBJECT_ID('tablename'). Then, the real problem becomes on how to update your data. I have no idea how you can achieve that if ids are all different, but you can probably use some LIKEs or something like that to match the text.

One complication is that all quotes (') inside the string must be quoted again, this makes query writing a bit cumbersome

Comment: `sp_MSForEachDB` has bugs, see https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb

Comment: @siggermannen Thank you for your response. Are the single quotes after "USE" and "END" necessary, and can both "somevalue" and "somethingorOther" be of the same field? Example, the misspellings are for the same column but I only need to edit one letter. So can it be like SET QuestionText = 'Mental' WHERE QuestionText = 'Metal'? That is literally what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: It's a string so yeah, they are necessary. That's how you work with dynamic sql. You create a string with code, and then you execute it. And yes, the query was just a sample, you can use any kind of sql in there you want. You can also use multiple updates, Selects or whatever else. But as I said. You need to quote every quote. Try by running a select instead of update. That will ensure you are getting the right rows.

Comment: @siggemannen I ran the code using a select statement (I do not have write access), but it gives me error messages, saying "incorrect syntax". Thank you.

Comment: Did you quote the quotes

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do documentation work.

i )Prepare list of all `| ColumnName |TableName | DatabaseName | Server IP|` where spelling correction is require

By doing this automatic idea will come. OR you can then update question accordingly here along with sample data.

So far whatever I understood,
This is not tested and also ignore syntax error

Customized suiting your requirement.
For now it work only in one database.

```
Create table #Correction(WrongSpelling varchar(200),CorrectSpelling varchar(200))
insert into #Correction(WrongSpelling ,CorrectSpelling ) 
values('Person with a serious metal illness','Person with a serious mental illness')
,('sepprate','separate')

Create table #Dictionary(schema char(3),tablename varchar(100),columnname varchar(100)
, WrongSpelling varchar(200),  CorrectSpelling varchar(200))



create table #temp(schema char(3),tablename varchar(100),columnname varchar(100))

insert into #temp(schema,tablename,columnname)
select table_schema, table_name,column_name 
from information_schema.columns where column_name in('AnswerText','QuestionText')

insert into #Dictionary(schema ,tablename ,columnname , WrongSpelling,  CorrectSpelling)
select schema,tablename,columnname,WrongSpelling ,CorrectSpelling #temp t,#Correction C

Now loop thru #Dictionary using cursor,inside cursor block 
i) use dynamic query for update ii) use sp_executesql iii) use like in predicate.

It is optimize enough,also this is one time query so 
optmization do not matter,accuracy matter.

Test properly


Update A
set QuestionText=CorrectSpelling
from dbo.QuestionnaireQuestionLookup A
inner join #Dictionary dic on a.QuestionText =like '%'+dic.WrongSpelling+'%'
```

So do the cursor & dynamic query work and let us know

Comment: The spelling is only in two columns, "AnswerText", where "separate" is misspelled, and in "QuestionText", where "Mental" is misspelled as "Metal". That is it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @PLC8,check my edited